# Once the referendum is over, can the democratic proposals passed be implemented directly?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, governance

Is there any way to speed up the implementation of [democracy pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/democracy) proposals?

[image]

Comment: polkadot can be compiled wtih `--features fast-runtime` that will reduce the wait times dramatically (for testing purposes).

Answer (score 3):

By submitting it as an external motion in Council: if the proposal originates in Council as an external motion and the Technical Committee fast-tracks the proposal to move it to referenda queue, they can define the length of the enactment period: this means TC will define the voting period and the enactment period. However, if you submit it as a public proposal, both voting and enactment periods will last for 7 days.

Take into account that TC will only execute short voting periods if the proposal is defined as urgent: meaning these are used for emergency bug fixes or rapid implementation of new but battle-tested features into the runtime - the TC always takes into account the safety of the network as a whole.